# HP Bluetooth interface disabled after update kernel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, bluetooth, hp

When I use the *lsusb* command with kernel 4.4.0-28 the bluetooth interface works:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
```

But if I use a later kernel version, the bluetooth interface disappears. Nor is it listed with *rfkill* and *hciconfig*.

Is it possible to apply a patch to keep the driver?

PD: HP Elitebook 6930p - Ubuntu 16.04